# LESS mixin for color conversion: HEX to BASE64

Tags: hex, base64, type-conversion, less, mixins

Is there a LESS mixin that does the following conversion?

```
#371541
```

to:

```
   data:image/svg+xml;base64,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
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Short Answer: "No" (not that I am aware of)

The longer answer is:

**First**, why? A straight color is far better to do than making that color into an image fed by a data uri. It is less code and I would suspect faster to process.

**Second**, if you *must have it*, then you will...

*Either **(1)*** need to do your own color conversion mixin. You could do this manually for every color you may want to convert through pattern matching. Something like:

```
.convert64(#371541) {
   data:image/svg+xml;base64,...[your data string for 3711541]
}
.convert64(#371542) {
   data:image/svg+xml;base64,...[your data string for 3711542]
}
```

Where you need to set a match for every hexcolor you might want to convert and have a preconfigured data string to output. ***This, of course, would be pointless unless you are only talking about a handful of numbers.***

*Or **(2)***, do [some type of javascript solution to encode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3709391/node-js-base64-encode-a-downloaded-image-for-use-in-data-uri), which [LESS can process](http://lesscss.org/#-javascript-evaluation).

Comment: i want to do this because i'm trying to create a cross-browser linear-gradient LESS mixin. For IE <= 8 you need that.
http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/

Comment: @ndrizza: If so, then why not use the `filter` like that site you linked to does (it does not use data uri's for IE 6-9, but the `filter` property for IE).

Comment: you are right. when is the 'image/svg+xml' used? why should i generate this?

Comment: @ndrizza: It is generated when you are trying to support an `svg` background for IE9 which allows IE9 to have "multiple stops" (which apparently is not supported by the `filter` command; it only allows the start and stop color, with no color change at middle stop points like modern CSS3 gradients). So it is only needed in the one case where you might try to enhance the IE9 experience to be better than an IE <= 8 experience (if you are using multiple stops). You will have to determine if that is worth the effort to support.

Comment: ok thanks, yes i need to support starting form IE 7 upwards :(. i'll try a js hack. i'll post the solution as soon as i have one.

Comment: @ndrizza: based on my reading of colorzilla's info, you _cannot get_ that kind of support (mid-point color stops) in IE7 and IE8 (else, I would assume, they would have a solution for it). The `svg` solution only affects IE9.