# Create Thumbnail Image using Windows Azure Blob Storage

Tags: node.js, azure, sdk

I am trying to use the azure-sdk-for-node to save a streamed image to Windows Azure blob storage but without success.  Below is the function that I call and pass the video object with the thumbnail property.  Initially I fetch the image using the request object which fetches the image from another website and turn that into a base64 object which in turn gets converted into a stream object because Azure blob service uses createBlockBlobFromStream method as I couldn't use createBlockBlobFromFile or createBlockBlobFromText to upload the image to blob storage.

```
var azure = require('azure')
    , uuid = require('node-uuid')
    , http = require('http')
    , url = require('url')
    , mmm = require('mmmagic')
    , Magic = mmm.Magic
    , stream = require('stream');

function createVideoThumbnail(video, callback){
    var bs = azure.createBlobService(config.storageAccount, config.storageAccessKey, config.blobHost);
    var sURL = video.Thumbnail;
    var oURL = url.parse(sURL);
    var client = http.createClient(80, oURL.hostname);
    var request = client.request('GET', oURL.pathname, {'host': oURL.hostname});

    request.end();
    request.on('response', function (response) {
        var type = response.headers["content-type"];
        var prefix = "data:" + type + ";base64,";
        var body = "";

        response.setEncoding('binary');
        response.on('end', function () {
            var base64 = new Buffer(body, 'binary').toString('base64');
            var data = prefix + base64;
            console.log('base64 image data ' + video.Thumbnail + ': ' + data + '\n');

            var decodedImage = new Buffer(data, 'base64');
            var magic = new Magic(mmm.MAGIC_MIME_TYPE);

            magic.detect(decodedImage, function(err, result) {
                if(err) {
                    throw err;
                }

                var bytes = 0;
                var imageStream = new stream.Stream();
                imageStream.writable = true;

                imageStream.write = function(buf) {
                    bytes += buf.length;
                    imageStream.emit('data', buf);
                };

                imageStream.end = function(buf) {
                    //if(arguments.length) {
                        imageStream.write(buf);
                    //}

                    imageStream.writable = false;
                    imageStream.emit('end');
                    console.log(bytes + ' bytes written');
                };

                var options = {}
                console.log('mmm = ' + result + '\n');
                options.contentType = result;
                options.contentTypeHeader = result;

                console.log('\n');
                bs.createBlockBlobFromStream(config.imageContainer, uuid().replace(/-/gi, "").toLowerCase() + '.jpg', imageStream, decodedImage.length, options, function(error, blobResult, response) {
                    if (error)
                        console.log('got error = ' + JSON.stringify(error) + '\n');

                    if (blobResult)
                        console.log('blobResult = ' + JSON.stringify(blobResult) + '\n');

                    if (response)
                        console.log('response = ' + JSON.stringify(response) + '\n');

                    // now store in Azure blob storage
                    callback();
                });

                imageStream.end(decodedImage);
            });
        });
        response.on('data', function (chunk) {
            if (response.statusCode == 200) body += chunk;
        });
    });
}
```

and this is how I call it:

```
createVideoThumbnail(video, function(){
    console.log("returning from create thumbnails\n\n");
});
```

The function is not working it hangs and won't print out the the final log statement:

```
console.log("returning from create thumbnails\n\n");
```

However the base64 does seem to work as I am getting this for the encoding:

data:image/jpeg;base64,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

mmm = application/octet-stream
5283 bytes written

But I am not getting any of these log statements being printed:

```
if (error)
    console.log('got error = ' + JSON.stringify(error) + '\n');

if (blobResult)
    console.log('blobResult = ' + JSON.stringify(blobResult) + '\n');

if (response)
    console.log('response = ' + JSON.stringify(response) + '\n');
```

So I am presuming it is hanging somewhere or I have not structured my code properly.  Can anybody see what I am doing wrong ?

Cheers
Rob

My sources:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wavirtualmachinesforlinux/thread/47bfe142-c459-4815-b09e-bd0a07ca18d5

[Node.js base64 encode a downloaded image for use in data URI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3709391/node-js-base64-encode-a-downloaded-image-for-use-in-data-uri)

Comment: First off I would suggest switching to the request module: https://github.com/mikeal/request since the default implementation is rather messy and your `body += chunk` is casting the incoming buffer into a string.

Comment: hi generalhenry, I had a look at the request object and the examples but I'm guessing I still have to use the stream module require('stream') to turn the base64 encoded file into a stream object and then do request('http://google.com/doodle.png').pipe(imageStream); Is that about right to you? Can you give me a rough outline of the code you think I need to implement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Valery Jacobs on msdn forums was able to come up with the answer.  It's a nice clean solid solution using the stream, request and util object.

:)

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowsazurepurchasing/thread/25c7705a-4ea0-4d9c-af09-cb48a031d06c

Answer (score 0):

Here's my simplified version.  Since magic needs to operate on the whole file, there's no point in using the streaming blog API, instead this is written for the text api.  `body` will be a buffer of the image, I suspect azure will be happy with it sans encoding, call toString('encoding') if it does need it.

```
var azure = require('azure')
    , uuid = require('node-uuid')
    , request = require('request')
    , mmm = require('mmmagic')
    , Magic = mmm.Magic
    , stream = require('stream')
    , bs = azure.createBlobService(config.storageAccount, config.storageAccessKey, config.blobHost);

function createVideoThumbnail(video, callback){
  var sURL = video.Thumbnail;
  request(sURL, {encoding:null}, function (err, res, body) {
    // encoding:null makes request return a buffer, which is ideal to run magic.detect on
    magic.detect(body, function (err, res) {
      console.log(res);
      var container = config.imageContainer;
      var blob = uuid().replace(/-/gi, "").toLowerCase() + '.jpg';
      var text = body; //might need to be converted into a string, I don't have azure setup to test
      var options = {
        contentType: res,
        contentTypeHeader: res
      };
      bs.createBlockBlobFromText(container, blob, text, options, function(error, blobResult, response) {
        if (error)
          console.log('got error =', error);  
          // if you give console.log multiple arguments, it will format each of them, 
          // no need to manipulate objects into strings manually

        if (blobResult)
          console.log('blobResult =', blobResult);

        if (response)
          console.log('response =', response);

        // now store in Azure blob storage
        callback();
      });
    });
  });
}
```

edit: temp file version

```
var azure = require('azure')
    , uuid = require('node-uuid')
    , request = require('request')
    , mmm = require('mmmagic')
    , Magic = mmm.Magic
    , fs = require('fs')
    , bs = azure.createBlobService(config.storageAccount, config.storageAccessKey, config.blobHost);

function createVideoThumbnail(video, callback){
  var sURL = video.Thumbnail;
  var name = uuid().replace(/-/gi, "").toLowerCase() + '.jpg';
  var ws = fs.createWriteStream('./tmp/' + name);
  request(sURL, {encoding:null})
    .pipe(ws).on('close', function () {
    console.log('downloaded');
    magic.detectFile('./tmp/' + name, function (err, res) {
      var container = config.imageContainer;
      var blob = uuid().replace(/-/gi, "").toLowerCase() + '.jpg';
      var options = {
        contentType: res,
        contentTypeHeader: res
      };
      bs.createBlockBlobFromFile(container, name, './tmp/' + name, function (err) {
        callback();
      });
    });
  });
}
```

Comment: This solution bothers me as it requires buffering the entire stream in memory.  Another solution might be redirecting the raw stream to a temporary file, detecting the type of the file using magic, the using createBlockBlobFromFile to directly load the file into blob storage.
I suspect the issues with base64 encoding are just the base64 encoding start and end tags.

Comment: Given that it's a thumbnail I suspect the memory use is not a big issue, but yes, I'll rewrite it with a tmp file since that should get the blog upload working right which is the big issue.

Comment: I added a temp file version, as a note it lacks error handling and doesn't clean up after it self (it leave the temp file). Also only tested as far as download and detected.