# Saving binary data to azure blob storage using createBlockBlobFromText?

Tags: angularjs, azure, file-upload, azure-blob-storage

Based on this [post](https://www.bountysource.com/issues/1516527-blobservice-createblockblobfromtext-should-allow-a-buffer-to-be-passed-in), this should be possible. However, I can't make it work. One confusing part is that am I using the correct version of azure-storage? In that post, timm said one year ago

> This is released in 0.9.x.

However, there is no version of 0.9. The latest of azure-storage is 0.6.0.

Here is my server code (node.js):

```
var buf = new Buffer(upd.picture, 'binary');
blobService.createBlockBlobFromText(containerName, fileName, buf, function (error, result, response) {
});
```

On client side (angular.js), the binary data is read like this:

```
var file = document.getElementById('file').files[0];
var reader = new FileReader();
reader.onloadend = function (e) {
    upd.picture = e.target.result;
    ....
}
reader.readAsBinaryString(file);
```

For my testing, I uploaded a jpg image, the file saved in azure blob can't be displayed in web browser. However, if I use createBlockBlobFromLocalFile to upload the file, it works. What did I do wrong?

**UPDATE:**

Okay, I finally figured it out. I just need to change one line above to

```
var buf = new Buffer(upd.picture.substr(23), 'base64');
```

The problem was that the file is already converted to based64 with header "data:image/jpeg;base64," which messed up the binary data.

Comment: May be you'd need to provide the Content-Type header saying it's an image. Have a look at that post : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15450102/create-thumbnail-image-using-windows-azure-blob-storage

Comment: I wondered that too, but what do I suppose to put as content-type?

Comment: I tried to add options = { contentType: 'image/jpeg' , contentTypeHeader: 'image/jpeg' }, but it didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

To clarify the version issue, the version [timm](https://www.bountysource.com/issues/1516527-blobservice-createblockblobfromtext-should-allow-a-buffer-to-be-passed-in) mentioned is the version of "[azure](https://www.npmjs.com/package/azure)" module. Now the Azure Storage SDK is released with "[azure-storage](https://www.npmjs.com/package/azure-storage)" module.
Using the latest module might resolve your issue.

Comment: Thanks for clarification.